# How to Read Record From Database in ASP.MVC Core using Entity Framework Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sql-server-2014, entity-framework-core

I am working on simple MVC 6 app with .NET Core 1.0 and trying to read data from database using Entity Framework Core 1.0 and getting following error in my LINQ query from where I am trying to read table; The LINQ query is in HomeController class

### Error

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid object name 'TestModel'.
```

### Model Class

```
[Table("TestTable")]
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### TestDbContext

```
public class TestDbContext: DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options): base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().ToTable("TestModel");
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);


        services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UCASAppDatabase")));


        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

### project.json

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0"
```

### appsettings.json

```
{
"ApplicationInsights": {
"InstrumentationKey": ""
},
"Logging": {
 "IncludeScopes": false,
 "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
 }
 },
 "ConnectionStrings": {
  "UCASAppDatabase": "Data Source=mydb;Initial Catalog=UCAS-DB;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True"
 }
}
```

### HomeController (trying to read table here!)

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(TestDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

  public IActionResult About()
    {
            var query = (from b in _context.TestModels
                         select b).ToList();

            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Not sure what I missing here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Fault found error, was giving wrong table name in override OnModelCreating

```
public class TestDbContext: DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options): base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().ToTable("TestTable");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in EF Core data annotatios do not work, all mapping will perform with fluent api